# Website links not working on google chrome but work fine for firefox

Tags: php, html, css, magento

When I open my [website](http://mazenta.in/c/) in Firefox it works fine. 
However, in Google Chrome the sign-in button, add-to cart button, etc do not work.

Please help me and if required some code please tell me i will update question with code.

Comment: You'll need to include some code

Comment: Would help if you would include your HTML/CSS code for those effected errors.

Comment: You have some overlaping styles (box-products carousel slide) ...remove it or use z-index

Comment: Most likely firefox are fixing your issues and display the page as best it can, but chrome does as you made the page.

Comment: its not about css but the link on signin and addtocart not working.but when i open it in firefox signin link working.you can check my website url is given in question.All Answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Leave all css at the top head.

All js after /body
also make sure the jquery is at the first after the /body

Answer (score 0):

It is your css and you need to add a margin-top:30px to clear the other div from the covered div. Tested and working on Chrome.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.col-lg-9 {
width: 75%;
margin-top: 30px;
```

}

[image]

Comment: thank you.
please check the product page on both browsers and please help .i will be very thank full to you.

Comment: it works Thank You.please see product page and login page also

Comment: Ok, it looks like it used a different div structure on that page, and I only checked the home page. Add the margin to this area instead to fix all the pages.

Comment: #header .header1 .menu-top {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    min-height: 0px !important;
    height: 10px;
    MARGIN-TOP: 30PX;
}

Comment: above code is for which page login or product page.

Comment: Please see View Cart Page It is looking very bad please help

Comment: It looks like you are adding alot of custom codes. The site acted up but this is what I got and it was working good. .col-lg-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.registered-users {     margin-top: 55px;
}
.col-lg-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.new-users {     margin-top: 55px;
}
.footer1 .powered {     margin-top: 0px;
}
#header .header1 .menu-top {     margin-top: 30px;
}
body {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

Comment: Thank You.But It is working only for home page not for product page,login and view cart page.Please see these pages if possible please help.I am new to magento.

Comment: Thank you home page is working fine  but it is not working for product page.Please help

Comment: If I use this, it works on every page regardless of browser I use. .container {margin-bottom: 30px;}

Comment: no but i added some  custom css according to firefox

Comment: Thank You.I want to know is my website home page looks same in both browsers or not because some is saying it not looking same on both browsers.

Comment: Some can have not up to date browsers. One thing you have to keep in mind is, no website will 100% work on all devices or machines.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i tried use .container {margin-bottom: 30px;} on my google chrome product page but it is not working.